# Compare DataFrames for Different Rows regardless of row order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have been trying to compare two dataframes to find missing rows and different rows:

#### **Case 1:** Same number of rows and different rows:

In this case, I have same number of rows, but two different rows:

```
dict_a = {'Values 1':[15, 2, 3, 24, 5, 16], 'Values 2':[10, 7, 3, 5, 6, 23], 
          'Values 3': ["Apple", "Orange", "Kiwi", "Cherry", "Banana", "Grapes"]}
dict_b = {'Values 1':[15, 3, 3, 24, 5, 16], 'Values 2':[10, 7, 3, 5, 6, 23], 
          'Values 3': ["Apple", "Orange", "Kiwi", "Cherry", "Banana", "Grape"]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict_a)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict_b)
```

[image]

So, I can find the different row indexes using:

```
list(df1[~df1.isin(df2)].dropna(how = 'all').index)
```

This results in `[1, 5]`.

#### **Case 2:** Different number of rows and different rows:

In this case, I have different number of rows, and two different rows.

```
dict_a = {'Values 1':[15, 2, 3, 24, 1], 'Values 2':[10, 7, 3, 5, 6], 
          'Values 3': ["Apple", "Orange", "Kiwi", "Cherry", "Banana"]}
dict_b = {'Values 1':[15, 1, 3, 24, 5, 16], 'Values 2':[10, 7, 3, 5, 6, 23], 
          'Values 3': ["Apple", "Orange", "Kiwi", "Cherry", "Banana", "Grape"]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict_a)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict_b)

display(df1)
display(df2)
```

[image]

Here, first I check for missing rows. From this, I can find that it is the fifth index by comparing the dataframe with greater length with shorter length:

```
df2[~df2.index.isin(df1.index)]
```

I can also find the different rows:

```
df1[~df1.isin(df2)].dropna(how = 'all')
```

which are `[1, 4]`.

#### **Case 3: Interchanged rows, but same row data**

```
dict_a = {'Values 1':[2, 15, 3, 24, 5, 16], 'Values 2':[7, 10, 3, 5, 6, 23], 
          'Values 3': ["Orange", "Apple", "Kiwi", "Cherry", "Banana", "Grape"]}
dict_b = {'Values 1':[15, 2, 3, 24, 5, 16], 'Values 2':[10, 7, 3, 5, 6, 23], 
          'Values 3': ["Apple", "Orange", "Kiwi", "Cherry", "Banana", "Grape"]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict_a)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict_b)

display(df1)
display(df2)
```

However, the code doesn't work for interchanged rows. It needs to check if row already exists regardless of position and return a result "there are no different rows", but instead it says rows at index `[0, 1]` are different.

[image]

So, I am looking for a solution which can compare the two dataframes regardless of row order or position, missing rows, and different rows.

So, my goal is to compare two dataframes and return "missing rows" and also "different rows" i.e. which don't completely match each other. Is there a such a function which can actually compare the rows in this way?

Comment: there are a number of ways to do this, I think in your use case, if the columns align, use `pd.concat([df1,df2],keys['df1','df2'])` then you can use `.drop_duplicates` with its different arguments to get your desired rowset (see `keep=False, keep='first',keep='last')` from the docs. Another way that could work is to create a unique hash key based on certain fields and then use your `isin` method on that key to see the delta.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a great trick that I learned by accident pd.merge does a great job showing this

```
dict_a = {'Values 1':[2, 15, 3, 24, 5, 16], 'Values 2':[7, 10, 3, 5, 6, 23], 
          'Values 3': ["Orange", "Apple", "Kiwi", "Cherry", "Banana", "Grape"]}
dict_b = {'Values 1':[15, 2, 3, 24, 5, 16], 'Values 2':[10, 7, 3, 5, 6, 23], 
          'Values 3': ["Apple", "Orange", "Kiwi", "Cherry", "Banana", "Grape"]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict_a)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict_b)

df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2,how='outer',on=['Values 1','Values 2','Values 3'],indicator=True)
print(df3)
```

is your last case you can see that this solves the problem with order

```
   Values 1  Values 2 Values 3 _merge
0         2         7   Orange   both
1        15        10    Apple   both
2         3         3     Kiwi   both
3        24         5   Cherry   both
4         5         6   Banana   both
5        16        23    Grape   both
```

Now go back to an earlier case

```
dict_c = {'Values 1':[15, 2, 3, 24, 5, 16], 'Values 2':[10, 7, 3, 5, 6, 23], 
          'Values 3': ["Apple", "Orange", "Kiwi", "Cherry", "Banana", "Nut"]}
df4 = pd.DataFrame(dict_c)
df5 = pd.merge(df1,df4,how='outer', on=['Values 1','Values 2','Values 3'],indicator=True)
print(df5)
```

You get

```
   Values 1  Values 2 Values 3      _merge
0         2         7   Orange        both
1        15        10    Apple        both
2         3         3     Kiwi        both
3        24         5   Cherry        both
4         5         6   Banana        both
5        16        23    Grape   left_only
6        16        23      Nut  right_only
```

The indicators give you where they are different. Using the on variable also makes it so that you can use a subset of the columns to fix your problem.

Comment: that `indicator` is a lifesaver. But if the dataframes are big, then this merging on all columns will be expensive

Comment: Can I possibly use this as an all in one solution that works for all cases i.e. to compare any dataframes? If so, can you show how am I going to find "missing rows" and "different rows" in the end?

Comment: There is a real question on different vs. missing; if you have two items where one is misspelled, say bolt and blot, then you will get two missing or two different?  I use this to get three groups, those in both, those in df1 and not df2, and those in df2 and not df1.  
You could consider that if you get only in the left, they are missing in the right.  But when you have missing in both its difficult.

Comment: @Paul: Yes, I plan to use one table as my original and other as to check if its up to date with original. So, in that sense I suppose it would be either `how='left'` or `how='right'`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use sets -

```
s1 = set(df1.to_string(index=False, header=False).split('\n'))
s2 = set(df2.to_string(index=False, header=False).split('\n'))
for item in s1.union(s2):
    if item in s1.intersection(s2):
        print(f'{item}|both')
    elif item in s1:
        print(f'{item}|left_only')
    else:
        print(f'{item}|right_only')
#  1   7  Orange|right_only
#  5   6  Banana|right_only
# 24   5  Cherry|both
#  2   7  Orange|left_only
# 15  10   Apple|both
# 16  23   Grape|right_only
#  3   3    Kiwi|both
#  1   6  Banana|left_only
```

Answer (score 0):

For the missing rows, just use drop duplicates together with a concat

```
import pandas as pd
dict_a = {'Values 1':[2, 15, 3, 24, 5, 16, 2], 'Values 2':[7, 10, 3, 5, 6, 23,1], 
          'Values 3': ["Orange", "Apple", "Kiwi", "Cherry", "Banana", "Grape", "test"]}
dict_b = {'Values 1':[15, 2, 3, 24, 5, 16, 1], 'Values 2':[10, 7, 3, 5, 6, 23, 0], 
          'Values 3': ["Apple", "Orange", "Kiwi", "Cherry", "Banana", "Grape", "test"]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict_a)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict_b)
pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

[image]

For the different rows I suggest the following logic.
You compare the entire dataframe and check where the sum of the row is not equal to 3.

```
df1[(df1 == df2).apply(sum, axis = 1) != 3]
```

[image]

```
df2[(df1 == df2).apply(sum, axis = 1) != 3]
```

[image]